# pcl/pcl_config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: point-cloud-library

My environment is below.
・Operating System and version:windows 10 64bit
・Compiler:C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
・PCL Version:1.9.1
pcl_config.h not found as below error occurred when compiled under above env..
Certainly this header file is not included.
Let me know how to solve it.
    PS C:\pcl\pcl\examples\common> g++ -o minmax -I ../../io/include -I     ../../common/include .\example_get_max_min_coordinates.cpp
    In file included from ../../common/include/pcl/PCLHeader.h:10,
    from ../../common/include/pcl/point_cloud.h:47,
    from ../../io/include/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:42,
    from .\example_get_max_min_coordinates.cpp:2:
    ../../common/include/pcl/pcl_macros.h:64:10: fatal error: 
  pcl/pcl_config.h: No such file or directory
    #include 
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

`pcl_config.h` is generated via `pcl_config.h.in` by the [`cmake` tool](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html). So it seems that compilation did not finish correctly.

### Longer answer

- Please make sure you have compiled the relevant modules of PCL (at least pcl-core) before proceeding
- You might prefer a pre-built installation from [releases](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/releases) or distributed by a package/source manager of your choice
- PCL makes heavy use of other libraries and it is best to supply the dependencies (as mentioned below) via CMake or manually via the `-I` and `-l` options. If you provide the location of `pcl_config.h`, the compiler will complain about `Eigen` next.

The build instructions are available [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/README.md#compiling). **TL;DR**: After satisfying the dependencies (cmake, c++ compiler, boost, eigen, flann, vtk and other depending on use-case), run the following commands

```
cd $PCL_SOURCE_DIR
mkdir -p build; cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make -j8
```

Feel free to use any build generator (like Ninja) or change build type to `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo` as per your needs.

Comment: pcl_config.h is made as your advice.

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: wrong. The example code was compiled by mingw64 g++. pcl_config.h could be made but did not try to compile it yet. After compiling, inform again.